# How to display AlertDialog on List Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

`ContactsDataList` is an Array List that contains the data of all Contacts.

I have written following code that pass data to List Adapter

```
adapter= new ContactsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), contactsDataList);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_contacts);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

On List View, I want to Launch `Call_Action` event, whenever user clicks on any item in List.

I have written following code in Adapter, but its giving me this error message

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.

```
contactsHeading.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to call "+contactsHeading + "?"  );
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + contactsText));
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(v.getContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            return;
                        }
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
```

Kindly guide me how to resolve this error message.

Comment: You should move your AlertDialog's creation logic from your adapter to your activity (or whatever android component has the new `ContactsAdapter` reference) and make them communicate via a listener inside the adapter, as some lifecycle events might cause it to crash (all dialogs should be hidden at `onPause()`). From there you should pass your activity as the `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor parameter and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the **Context** you passed into the **AlertDialog.Builder**.

In this line:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
```

Replace

```
context
```

with

```
[YourActivityName].this
```

Comment: When i write this new `AlertDialog.Builder(ContactsActivity.this).create();`..It gives me following error message `ContactsActivity is not an enclosing class`

Comment: What is ContactsActivity currently derived from? It should extend an Activity class.

Comment: its derived from AppCompactActivity

Comment: That should be right. Is your ListAdapter enclosed in your Activity? If not, try to nest it under your Activity.

Comment: Yes I added `ListAdapter` in `ContactsActivity` `onCreate` Method

Comment: At this point it's really hard to tell what the exact problem is, could you update this thread with your entire Activity code?

Comment: Thanks, i was passing `getApplicationContext` instead of `this` to my adapter constructor. Its working Now. Thanks a lot ! :)